# How to create a service or shell scripts to run a project within virtualenv?

Tags: python, shell, nginx, virtualenv

Here's are the commands i'm using to start my project:

```
nginx -s stop
workon my_project_env
pkill -f uwsgi -9
uwsgi -x /root/my_project/My_web_api/My_web_api.xml
deactivate
nginx
```

I want to make sure that this project starts even if the server reboots.

But writing a shell command file as `xxx.sh` is not going to work,

as shell command won't simply work in virtualenv.

All of the command above will just work in the main terminal,

but some command must work on the virtualenv.

How can i work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call the uwsgi command using the virtualenv's file for uwsgi. that way you won't need to activate the virtualenv.

Something like below,

```
/path/to/virtualenvs/project-name/bin/uwsgi -x /root/my_project/My_web_api/My_web_api.xml
```

All the commands that need to be run using virtualenv should be called this way, so that you won't need to activate the virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you Akash, i tryed the commond as you said, and it works, helps a lot! Can you tell me more about these situation? 

e.g. I think i don't need to activate the virtualenv and run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, but run this command instead:

`/path/to/virtualenvs/project-name/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

But, if i need to activate the virtualenv and run some command like `pkill -f uwsgi -9`, how can i make it right?

Comment: @Elliott killing uwsgi has nothing to do with the virtualenv. you can try pkill uwsgi without activating virtualenv and it will also work. it might not give expected result if there are multiple uwsgi process running, but i doubt that it will be the case.

Comment: Thank you @Akash Ranjan, it really helps!

Comment: I have tried since two days ago, but the response says:`Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.` I think i need to get more reputation, and your answer will be upvoted automatically. If not, i will come back and check.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using `souce ./xxx.sh` will work(i used to use `./xxx.sh` ), but with Akash Ranjan's help, i know that it is not the right way for situation like this.